# Plot the intersection in every two list elements

Tags: r, list, set-intersection

Given a list of 16 elements, where each element is a named numeric vector, I want to plot the length of the intersection of names between every 2 elements. That is; the intersection of element 1 with element 2, that of element 3 with element 4, etc.

Although I can do this in a very tedious, low-throughput manner, I'll have to repeat this sort of analysis, so I'd like a more programmatic way of doing it.

As an example, the first 5 entries of the first 2 list elements are:

```
topGenes[[1]][1:5]

3398   284353   219293     7450    54658 
2.856363 2.654106 2.653845 2.635599 2.626518 

topGenes[[2]][1:5]
1300    64581     2566     5026   146433 
2.932803 2.807381 2.790484 2.739735 2.705030
```

Here, the first row of numbers are gene IDs & I want to know how many each pair of vectors (a treatment replicate) have in common, among, say, the top 100.

I've tried using lapply() in the following manner:

```
vectorOfIntersectLengths <- lapply(topGenes, function(x) lapply(topGenes, function(y) length(intersect(names(x)[1:100],names(y)[1:100]))))
```

This only seems to operate on the first two elements; topGenes[[1]] & topGenes[[2]].

I've also been trying to do this with a for() loop, but I'm unsure how to write this. Something along the lines of this:

```
lengths <- c()
for(i in 1:length(topGenes)){
  lens[i] <- length(intersect(names(topGenes[[i]][1:200]),
names(topGenes[[i+1]][1:200])))
}
```

This returns a 'subscript out of bounds' error, which I don't really understand.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: maybe see `?expand.grid` but I'm not really sure what you're asking.  would you please provide `dput(topGenes)` or a representative example subset?

Comment: Sure. Here are the first 10 entries of the first 2 list elements:

Comment: Sorry, hit 'enter' too soon on that reply. I've edited the post for (hopefully) clarity.

Comment: ah you want the intersection of names -- let me edit the solution to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
# make some fake data
set.seed(123)
some_list <- lapply(1:16, function(x) {
  y <- rexp(100)
  names(y) <- sample.int(1000,100)
  y
})

# identify all possible pairs
pairs <- t( combn(length(some_list), 2) )
# note: you could also use:  pairs <- expand.grid(1:length(some_list),1:length(some_list))
# but in addition to a-to-b, you'd get b-to-a, a-to-a, and b-to-b

# get the intersection of names of a pair of elements with given indices kept for bookkeeping
get_intersection <- function(a,b) {
  list(a = a, b = b, 
       intersection = intersect( names(some_list[[a]]), names(some_list[[b]]) ) 
  )
}

# get intersection for each pair
intersections <- mapply(get_intersection, a = pairs[,1], b = pairs[,2], SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

# print the intersections
for(indx in 1:length(intersections)){
  writeLines(paste('Intersection of', intersections[[indx]]$a, 'and',
                   intersections[[indx]]$b, 'contains:', 
                   paste( sort(intersections[[indx]]$intersection), collapse=', ') ) )
}
```

Comment: Almost! I can see the intersecting lengths in the resulting vector, along with the self intersections.

Comment: It does. The output looks a little funny, but the names of the intersecting elements that I"m looking for are definitely in there. When I run the code, the output, intersections, looks like this:

Comment: List of 256
         $ :List of 3
          ..$ a           : int 1
          ..$ b           : int 1
          ..$ intersection: chr [1:100] "3398" "284353" "219293" "7450" ...
         $ :List of 3
          ..$ a           : int 2
          ..$ b           : int 1
          ..$ intersection: chr [1:3] "121260" "3934" "29890"

The last line shows the intersection in names of the first 2 list elements of topGenes and I'm guess that the first intersection, of length 100, is the first element with itself. Works though! :-)

Comment: @Forest I updated the answer with a print routine to console.  You could easily make it a print to file a by changing the `con=` argument to `writeLines`.  It's a ragged-right table, so maybe XML or JSON would be good ways to represent it, but if you're just manually using it you could copy or pipe the output to whatever works for you.